# jquery calls are returining $ is undefined errors

Tags: jquery

I have a problem running my jsp pages.

My jsp pages has reference to some .js file say (file1.js) and in file1.js I'm invoking the jquery calls like `$(document).ready`. The IE browser is complaining about the error:

> SCRIPT5009: `'$' is undefined file1.js, line 225 character 1`

I see the same exception on Firefox as well.

I have included the `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`  and also `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/file1.js"></script>` in my jsp.

Comment: be sure that file1.js is included after jQuery inclusion

Comment: can you show us the rest of `$(document).ready..`

Comment: my code have call like these,----$("document").ready( function() { somefun();}); and                                                               $("document").ready( function() { some lines of code });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check that you include the jQuery library
- `file1.js` append to document after jQuery library load (if you already add it).

Add jQuery library like following before any other js load

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### And one important note

Don't forget to place all your jQuery code within

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code
});
```

in short

```
$(function() {
   // your code
});
```

Comment: Including the library before any other js includes resolved the problem. Thank you very much for the great assistance. Keep up the great work :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this jquery library in `<head>` section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or Try with `jQuery.noConflict()`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: this library include is not sufficient for my code to work?                                                           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>